# How can I get Google to index dynamic URLs?

Tags: seo, google, google-search-console, search-engine-indexing, dynamic

I'm very new to SEO and site indexing and I'm trying to get my website to be indexed properly on Google.

My site has dynamic URLs that are based on their date (e.g., `example.com/day/3-7-2018`), I don't really have a way of making Google recognize this pattern. I've been using the Google Search Console, but almost nothing works right now. It all says unavailable for the most part. It also is failing to update my description, which I know can take up to week.

This is the only code I've entered that is related to SEO:

```
<meta name="description" content="KO Today is a student-made daily scheduler website for the Kingswood Oxford School. It shows the block schedule for every day of the year, aswell as additional information such as weather, fact of the day, and many more.">
```

My site map is also pretty blank. What might help with getting Google to index these dynamic URLs?

Answer (score 1):

Google will update your descriptions once it crawls the pages with changes. It may take some time for Google to crawl all of your updated pages depending upon how often Google crawls your site. You can view how many pages Google is crawling on your site each day here:

https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/crawl-stats?hl=en&authuser=0&siteUrl=

You said that nothing seems to be working and that it's unavailable. Are you saying that Google may not be able to read your pages properly? Visit this URL and try out some of your page URLs. Click Fetch and Render and then click the result. Google will show you how it reads your page and whether it was able to properly crawl it or not.

https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/googlebot-fetch?hl=en&authuser=0&siteUrl=

The meta content description that you provided looks acceptable and Google should begin adding that to your search results once it crawls the page, as long as your meta tags are properly placed in your head tag.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the detailed response, I'll definately try. My issue with the URLs is that the urls are generated through HTACCESS and relative to the GET content. And I'm having each page with a date query the database for the content for each date. Also, on the googlebot thing, it shows nothing. My page URLs technically don't exist, that's the issue.

Comment: If your pages exist and Google doesn't see them then this likely means Google is either blocked by your robots.txt or your pages don't return a status 200. You can check the status of your pages by entering them in here: http://tools.seobook.com/server-header-checker/ If they don't return a status 200 then you have to make them return a status 200 (OK).

Comment: It returned a status 200 on the base url. But extensions that are relative to the URL don't work. eg. kotoday.org/day/3-7-2018 or kotoday.org/day/5-2-2018